# Where can I find all three words of Champion's Spirit shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

Falskaar adds one shout to the game called Champions Spirit. Where can I find all three words of Champion's Spirit shout in Falskaar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three words of the shout can be found at: **Dragonbone Perch**, **Watervine Chasm**, and **[Grimrott Grotto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zriGs.jpg)**.

Note that the Watervine Chasm word wall is *not* the one in the main central chamber (the first very large chamber you get to). It is in the large room in the third cell, right before the Dwemer ruins.

<sup>Source: [Alexander J. Velicky's (Falskaar mod author) post at the Bethesda Forums - Falskaar Thread #2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200219173439/https://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1466924-rel-falskaar-thread-2/page-6#entry22884518)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

It's in **Ruins of Vizemundsted**, Dragonbone Perch and Grimrott Grotto. The one in Watervine Chasm is broken.

Comment: What do you mean by "*The one in Watervine Chasm is broken*"? I'm pretty sure I found a word wall of the shout at Watervine Chasm. Also, do you mean that there are four word walls for the three words of the Champion's Spirit shout?

Comment: @galacticninja Watervine Chasm end up in Vizemundsted. If you start in Watervine Chasm and follow the passage deeper you'll find a word wall that actually belongs to Vizemundsted. The other in Watervine Chasm is broken and has a lot of crates and boxes stacked into it.